# Compare and display query result mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 queries that I want to compare and display

- Compare the 2 queries for matching
- if match show image, if not show placeholder image

```
$variable1 = " SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT img, ID from tbl1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT img, ID from tbl2 
) as everything";
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array...){
$row1 = $a['img'];
$rowA = $a['ID'];
}
```

Compare with

```
$variable2 = "SELECT img, ID FROM tbl3";
while($b = mysqli_fetch_array...){
$row2 = $b['img'];
$rowB = $b['ID'];
}
```

I tried the foreach looping through each row to compare

```
foreach($rowB as $rowC){
if($rowC == $rowA)...
echo'<table>'.$row1.'</table>';
}else{
echo'<table>'.$row2.'</table>';
}
```

Seems like the entire result is repeated by the number of matches. I tried nesting one query into the other along with a host of other trials. Could use some guidance.

Comment: Do you actually execute any of these queries? It does not look like it here.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: yes sir...the queries work, just not the desired result. It repeats dependent on how many matches are found

Comment: If you're only showing us narrow slices of the code it's really hard to say where it's going wrong. A lot of the things shown here are missing important context. What is  `$rowC`? Those aren't shown being defined. Names like `$rowA` are really opaque, it needs a better name. The whole problem here needs to be defined more specifically in terms of *input* and *output*.